# How to use the keyboard with the date picker

Tags: org-mode

If I call C-c C-s, the date picker is showing up, but I can just use the mouse to pick a date. How am I able to pick a date in the date picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the excellent [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html).

Long story short: `org` tries hard to make sense of keyboard input. `+4d` for "4 days from now"; `Mon` for "next Monday" and more.

As the manual says:

> The actions of the date/time prompt may seem complex, but I assure you they will grow on you, and you will start getting annoyed by pretty much any other way of entering a date/time out there.

Comment: The same section describes how you can control the calendar from the minibuffer, so you can pick a date from the calendar by navigating to it with the keyboard and press RET, if that is what you are looking for.